# How make Eclipse uses maven projects even if Workspace resolution is not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

In theory, enabling Workspace resolution should make Eclipse to use the current project rather to go to the repository.

But it may fail, for different reasons. In my case, two projects A and A-test. Both of them have

- many subprojects/modules
- a main pom.xml that mentions such modules

I imported all of them in the same workspace.

Now, when running project in A-test, the only way to see the effect of a change in A is do a `mvn install`, so the jar is updated in local repository.

Enabling workspace resolution wasn't helping. Although, it sort of works when Debugging from Eclipse. A real mess.

So, how can I make sure projects in A-test are looking at Eclipse's A?

Comment: I didn't see this question clearly stated and answer. Some candidates were related to interactions between war and jar, or related to more specific issues. I tried to make the question more general. I don't think now it's a duplicated.

Comment: I created a new workspace and I got the project referring workspace version of the project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the workspace resolution is not exact. When projects are related through a common/global pom.xml, it seems to work.

So, in my case, per project in A-test, I did

- Right click, Build Path, Config Build path
- Tab "Projects": add all the A projects (in my case, that's safe)
- Tab "Order and Export": make sure A projects are BEFORE projects in M2. I just move all the A projects to top.

Now, when I ran a project in A-test, it's looking at A.

NB:
 - Eclipse Oxygen
 - A does not depends on A-test, at all.